# Getting Youtube channel network name

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

How can I get a network name from a channel without authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the solution was to **scrape** that data from a website that posts these stats taken from the YouTube API (That is shared with them specially).